# Units, in brackets, right aligned in align environment

Tags: align, units

I need to supply the unit of the formulas I use, in square brackets, right aligned. I use the align environment. I have tried several things, like manually changing the style of the equation numbering to include the units, but I need to be able to toggle the units.

Any ideas on how to do this? Example of how I would like this feature to work:

```
\begin{align}
 \CL(s) &= \frac{\OL(s)}{1 + \OL(s)}
    \unit{kg}
\end{align}
```

Comment: What does `\unit` (and `\CL` and `\OL`) look like/do?

Comment: \unit is a hypothetical macro to typeset and right-align the units. \CL and \OL are just macros for math-itallic CL and OL. Open-loop and closed-loop :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Remarks

You didn't provide `\CL` nor `\OL`, so I defined my own. You can use `&&` to skip to a new column in `align`.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty} %for cropping
\usepackage{amsmath,units}
\newcommand{\CL}{CL} % You didn't provide \CL
\newcommand{\OL}{OL} % You didn't provide \OL
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \CL(s) &= \frac{\OL(s)}{1 + \OL(s)} && [\CL] = \unit{kg}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: Nice! But not quite what I was looking for. I think i wasnt specific enough. I would like the [CL] = kg to align in all equations, so that for all equations it is horizontally aligned. Otherwise it looks really weird :-)

Comment: Take a look at the `siunitx` package. You can use it to compose units out and inside the mathmode, it's very useful.